# Unable to send attachments using chat.postMessage

Tags: php, slack-api

I'm working on automating a process where I work at a Managed Service Provider. I am trying to send a message to a user when they have a help desk ticket that goes overdue. I am triggering the following PHP script when that happens (simplified for this example):

```
<?php

$attachments = array(
    "fallback" => "Attachment 1 Fallback",
    "title" => "This is Attachment 1",
    "text" => "Attachment 1 text",
    "color" => "95baa9");

$ch = curl_init("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage");

$data = http_build_query([
    "token" => "xoxb-0000000000-00000000000", //omitting my token
    "channel" => "@johnsmith",
    "text" => "Here's some text!",
    "attachments" => json_encode($attachments),
    "as_user" => "true"
]);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $result;
```

Everything seems to be working except for attachments. When I trigger this script, I get the message without the attachment present, just the `text`. I am currently using `json_encode` because nesting the array inside of the `$data` array did not work.

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. I have tried a handful of variations but can't seem to nail this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage):

> A JSON-based array of structured attachments, presented as a URL-encoded string.

An example of expected value from the documentation:

```
[{"pretext": "pre-hello", "text": "text-world"}]
```

So you have to change your `$attachments` variable to this:

```
$attachments = array(
    array(
        "fallback" => "Attachment 1 Fallback",
        "title" => "This is Attachment 1",
        "text" => "Attachment 1 text",
        "color" => "95baa9"
    )
);
```

Here's what the result of the `json_encode` would be (Same format as the documentation):

```
[{"fallback":"Attachment 1 Fallback","title":"This is Attachment 1","text":"Attachment 1 text","color":"95baa9"}]
```

And this is how yours currently looks like:

```
{"fallback":"Attachment 1 Fallback","title":"This is Attachment 1","text":"Attachment 1 text","color":"95baa9"}
```